# How to round to 2 decimals in Java with floats

Tags: java, decimal

So, assuming, for some reason, floats are absolutely required in the programme one is creating despite the inaccuracy regarding decimal points, is there any method one can use to round them to 2 decimal places without converting them into doubles?

Comment: What's wrong with Math.round()? If you just need to display it, you can use format.

Comment: Don’t round the float data.  Just limit the number of places when you format it as a string.

Comment: Isn't that only used for doubles? I know I could convert the floats into doubles, but my programme is mostly composed of floats (I'm following from a textbook and the author decided to use floats because at my current level rounding isn't required). (for clinomaniac).

Comment: (to VGR) I'm not formatting it further. I've already done the necessary calculations with it, all is left is the rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static float roundFloat(float number, int scale)
{
    int pow = 10;

    for (int i = 1; i < scale; ++i)
        pow *= 10;

    float tmp = number * pow;

    return ( (float) ( (int) ((tmp - (int) tmp) >= 0.5f ? tmp + 1 : tmp) ) ) / pow;
}
```

Solid and fast.